# How to get a unique identifier of a key created and stored in iOS Keychain

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

When I create a new key in Keychain using `SecKeyCreateRandomKey` I would like to get `UUID` of this key (or any other unique `id`) and use this `id` to search for this key in Keychain in the future. How can I do it?

So far I managed only to provide `kSecAttrApplicationTag` as an attribute for future queries, but this solution is problematic as there can be any amount of keys created with this tag.

When looking at how keys are stored in Keychain database I see there is a `UUID` field there, though I cannot find a way to access it at the application level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have used the keychain third library for this ,If you feel comfortable check this out, I think it's easy and the best for your scenario.
https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift

Comment: thanks for suggestion, though the library you mentioned does not use `SecKeyCreateRandomKey` under the hood, so it is completely irrelevant in my case

Answer (score 0):

You could use `kSecAttrApplicationTag` to store a custom scheme with unique UID that you can generate independently.

Example:

```
kSecAttrApplicationTag -> {COMMON_ATTRIBUTE_PART}-{YOUR_GENERATED_UID}
```

Therefore you can store your generated UID and knowing the COMMON_ATTRIBUTE_PART you can later search for the key. That way you don't have to rely on UUID generated by keychain.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I actually do this way already, unfortunately as I described in the question, this solution has a drawback, you can store as many keys with the same tag in Keychain as you want. I want to know if there is a way to have a unique id on Keychain level, so it would be impossible to create another key in Keychain with the same id.